# C++ Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am currently working on a project in C++ which requires me to store letters from a text file in a binary tree.  I am supposed to go through the string and store the letters in the tree along with a number of how many times the letters occur.  I am not sure how to write the insert functions so that it stores both the letter and an integer.  This is what I have so far to store a single value in the tree.

```
void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *&nodePtr, TreeNode *&newNode)
{
    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        nodePtr = newNode;
    else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)
        insert(nodePtr->left, newNode);
    else
        insert(nodePtr->right, newNode);
}

void BinaryTree::insertNode(int num)
{
    TreeNode *newNode = NULL;
    newNode = new TreeNode;
    newNode->value = num;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    insert(root, newNode);
}
```

This is the class for the program:

```
class BinaryTree
{
    private:
        struct TreeNode
        {
            int value;
            TreeNode *left;
            TreeNode *right;
        };

        TreeNode *root;

        void insert(TreeNode *&, TreeNode *&);

    public:
        BinaryTree()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }
        void insertNode(int);
};
```

And int main:

```
int main()
{
    string filename;
    string filedata;
    BinaryTree tree;
    fstream file;
    cout << "Please enter a filename: ";
    cin >> filename;

    file.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (file)
    {
        while (file)
        {
            file >> filedata;
            //tree.insertNode(filedata, );
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I assume I need to add a string element to the insertNode function, but I am not sure how to store both values together in the tree.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have your `TreeNode` contain a `char` variable in addition to an `int` variable.  But are you required to code the `BinaryTree` or just utilize one?

Comment: I have to code it.  My problem is changing the insertNode function to insert the string as well as the integer.  Would I have to append the number to the end of the letter and store them together?

Comment: Why do you want to append them?? Just pass 2 variables to the `insertNode` and add one more data member to the class `TreeNode`

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Would the insert function code work as it is when the insertNode function code is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the structure of the struct `TreeNode` to this ::

```
struct TreeNode
{
    char value; // to store the char value of string
    int count; // number of times the character has occured
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right; 
};
```

It appears from your code that intend to use BST (going to the left if the value of the node is smaller than the root value, and vice versa in case value is more), in that case your `insertNode` and `insert` functions are completely wrong.

You shall first traverse the tree, using the character under consideration, if there is already a node for a specific value, you increment its count, if you hit a null, then you add a new node.

So, your `insert` and `insertNode` functions shall look like this::

```
void BinaryTree::insertNode(char value)
{
    if(root == NULL) {
        root = new TreeNode;
        root->value = value;
        root->count = 1;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if(root->value > value)
            insert(root->left, root, value);
        else
            insert(root->right, root, value);
    }
}

void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *current, TreeNode *parent, char value)
{
    if (current == NULL) {
        TreeNode *newNode = new TreeNode;
        newNode->value = value;
        newNode->count = 1;
        newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
        if(parent->value > newNode->value)
            parent->left = newNode;
        else
            parent->right = newNode;
    }
    else if (current->value > value)
        insert(current->left, current, value);
    else
        insert(current->right, current, value);
}
```

Here, I am considering that you want the first char of the string to be the root of the binary tree. I do not understand why you are creating a new node for every character. Moreover, you also do not need to pass the reference of the pointer to the function, since at no point you are modifying the pointers. And, I am passing 2 variables to the `insert` function, since yo insert to a tree you need to have a reference to the parent pointer. Hope this could help!